# Text area + column-count css causing focus outline to bleed into next column

Tags: css, angular, http

I'm currently writing a page using Angular and have created a dialog window for users to copy columns from an Excel document. This window consists of two large `textarea`s lined up as columns next to each other, which I achieved using css' `column-count` attribute.

The issue is that when the first `textarea` is focused, there is a glow around it. The bottom of the glow shows up in the next column above the second `textarea`. Is there something I can do to fix this?

I don't want to remove the glow because it helps the user know they're focusing on that input. Worst case scenario I'll just keep it as is.

[Here's a picture of what it looks like to have the first text area focused.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWFv.png)

*copy-paste-dialog.component.html*

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Copy/Paste Parts From Excel</h1>
<div id="dialogInput" mat-dialog-content>
  <div>
    <h4>Part Numbers</h4>
    <textarea rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Numbers" [(ngModel)]="result.supplierPNs" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Descriptions</h4>
    <textarea rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Descriptions" [(ngModel)]="result.descriptions" ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="dialogButtons" >
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="result">Submit</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

*copy-paste-dialog.component.css*

```
.dialogButtons {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#dialogInput {
    column-count: 2;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: While I originally accepted the first reply as an answer (It does work! It just removes the bottom glow all together and makes the textboxes kiss) I've found a better solution by just adding `#dialogInput div { padding: 5px 0; }` that keeps the bottom glow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it doesn't matter for you, you can just use flexbox:

```
.dialogButtons {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#dialogInput {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

#dialogInput div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

`display: flex` works likes a row, it puts the divs next to each other.
`flex: 1` means it will take the remaining space, so by giving both the divs within #dialoginput, it will take the even amount of space, which in this case is 50%.

At last, I added some margin.

Comment: Oh, that's perfect, thank you! I'll accept this as an answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me haha

Answer (score 0):

Flex-box instead of `column-count: 2` will solve this issue

CSS Change

```
.dialogButtons {
   margin: 10px 0;
}

#dialogInput {
  display: flex;
}

#dialogInput textarea {
  margin-right: 1em;
}


textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```